# How can rectangle-select-paste operations be done in Vim?

Tags: vim, geany

Rectangle-select-paste can be done in Geany, as shown here:

[image]

How can the equivalent be accomplished in Vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visual block](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/selecting-columns-with-visual-block-mode/). Check out the docs right in vim with `:help visual-block`.

From normal mode simply use **ctrl-v** to start block select. Then navigate from one corner of the block to the other and yank, insert, paste, change, delete or run a macro. The link above gives an excellent overview of the options.

You might also be interested in the vim plugin for [multiple cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors).

While super**user** is an excellent forum, this question would be a better fit under https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your solution. That's exactly what I need. Thanks also for your preemptive suggestion of the plugin for multiple cursors.